# AWS Application load balancer rule not working for cookies ? What could have gone wrong?

Tags: cookies, load-balancing, devops, aws-application-load-balancer, sticky-session

I work in the dev-ops team at my company. Recently, we shifted to aws's application load balancer and we are forwarding the request based on a cookie's value. For some reason, the rule isn't working and AWS doesn't support logs to get information on why a rule faied.

There could be 2 reasons for this, that we can think of:

1. Load balancer isn't able to read the cookie: We don't think this should be the issue as the applications under this load balancer are able to read and also print the cookies.
2. The load balancer doesn't read subsequent cookies after the first request: We have raised a concern with AWS on this and they are still to get back.

Meanwhile, can anyone point to any possible issues which we might be overlooking?

Comment: Facing similar issues. Is there something w.r.t. cookies that we are missing here ?

Comment: Since you are going through a load balancer, is it possible that you are hitting a different instance of the service.

Comment: He is stating in his question that the load balancer is not able to read the cookie, instances are able to. Question is why load balancer is unable to read, but instances can clearly read, understand and also print.